# Undot all files and folders in an external disk

Tags: batch-rename

I have thousands of doted files, folders and subfolders in an external hard disk drive. I want to recover all pictures within these folders. 
I want to undot them all to easily navigate this pictures.

I've tried renaming the folders, but It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: "navigate" So with Nautilus? If so: press control-h ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Name clashes

The first question you need to ask yourself is if there is a chance of name clashes. In other words; if there possibly exist both a *hidden* version and a non-hidden version of the same directory or file in one and the same directory.

#### From bottom to top

Assuming that is not the case, this is one of the situations you need to rename *from bottom to top*, since you cannot rename (move) files inside folders that were just renamed; the script will not find them anymore and break.

#### Making hidden files visible

Furthermore, while writing this answer, a comment of @Rinzwind just popped up above my head, mentioning pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will make all hidden files and folders visible, which is true of course.

If you nevertheless would like to rename the files and folders:

#### A script to do so

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil

directory = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith("."):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f[1:]))
    for dr in dirs:
        if dr.startswith("."):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, dr), os.path.join(root, dr[1:]))
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rename_dotted.py`
2. Open a terminal and type the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rename_dotted.py '<directory>'
   ```

   where `'<directory>'` is the directory, needs to be in quotes if it includes one or more spaces.

   As always, please first try on a sample.

Comment: As always a good example at python. +1. Should really get my feet wet in it as well.

Comment: @Videonauth Haha, thanks. The python `topdown=False` comes handy here :)